# Determining group size based entry and exit times of IDs in my df

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by

This gives me the entry and exit times of IDs in my df:

minmax = merged_df.groupby(['id'])['date'].agg([min, max])

```
result

id   min                 max

4900 2019-09-17 08:43:06 2019-09-17 09:38:20
4909 2019-09-17 08:43:06 2019-09-17 09:16:00
4911 2019-09-17 08:43:06 2019-09-17 09:43:58
4965 2019-09-17 09:27:14 2019-09-17 09:38:28
5134 2019-09-17 09:34:26 2019-09-17 09:38:27
5139 2019-09-17 09:37:03 2019-09-17 09:46:19
5141 2019-09-17 09:37:22 2019-09-17 12:06:30
5163 2019-09-17 09:38:03 2019-09-17 10:18:29
5170 2019-09-17 09:38:19 2019-09-17 12:47:49
```

This is how my DF structure looks like:

```
df

date                    x   y   id  

2019-09-17 08:43:06     206 210 4900
2019-09-17 08:43:06     234 236 4909
2019-09-17 08:43:06     251 222 4911
2019-09-17 08:43:07     231 244 4909
2019-09-17 08:43:07     252 222 4911
2019-09-17 08:43:07     207 210 4965
2019-09-17 08:43:08     234 250 5163
2019-09-17 08:43:08     252 222 4911
2019-09-17 08:43:08     206 210 4900
2019-09-17 08:43:09     252 222 4911
2019-09-17 08:43:09     206 210 4900
2019-09-17 08:43:09     223 247 4909
2019-09-17 08:43:10     206 210 4900
2019-09-17 08:43:10     229 237 4909
2019-09-17 08:43:10     252 222 4911
2019-09-17 08:43:12     226 241 4909
```

How can i create a new column in my DF that compares the entry points of the IDs in a given second and if they appeared in a same time range (for example same minute), then I would like to get something like to insert the groupsize, something like this:

```
df

date                    x   y   id      groupsize

2019-09-17 08:43:06     206 210 4900    3
2019-09-17 08:43:06     234 236 4909    3
2019-09-17 08:43:06     251 222 4911    3
2019-09-17 08:43:07     231 244 4909    3
2019-09-17 08:43:07     252 222 4911    3
2019-09-17 08:43:07     207 210 4965    1
2019-09-17 08:43:08     234 250 5134    1
2019-09-17 08:43:08     252 222 5139    2
2019-09-17 08:43:08     206 210 4900    3
2019-09-17 08:43:09     252 222 4911    3
2019-09-17 08:43:09     206 210 4900    3
2019-09-17 08:43:09     223 247 4909    3
2019-09-17 08:43:10     206 210 5141    2
2019-09-17 08:43:10     229 237 4909    3
2019-09-17 08:43:10     252 222 5163    2
2019-09-17 08:43:12     226 241 5170    2
```

How can i do this? Is this something anyone can help me out with?

I appreciate any hint!

Comment: What determines group size?

Comment: The groupsize is determined by the distinct IDs in a given second, only taking those IDs into consideration that emerged in the dataset in a similar time range (that could be defined to S intervals). Does this make sense? So the first groupsizes are 3, since ID 4900,4909 ad 4911 all emerged in second 6. While ID 4965 emerged alone in second 7, therefore the groupsize is 1.

Comment: got it, check solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, first lets merge the min and max values onto your data frame structure

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df3 = pd.merge(df,minmax,on='id',how='left')
                  date    x    y    id                 min                 max
0  2019-09-17 08:43:06  206  210  4900 2019-09-17 08:43:06 2019-09-17 09:38:20
1  2019-09-17 08:43:06  234  236  4909 2019-09-17 08:43:06 2019-09-17 09:16:00
2  2019-09-17 08:43:06  251  222  4911 2019-09-17 08:43:06 2019-09-17 09:43:58
3  2019-09-17 08:43:07  231  244  4909 2019-09-17 08:43:06 2019-09-17 09:16:00
4  2019-09-17 08:43:07  252  222  4911 2019-09-17 08:43:06 2019-09-17 09:43:58
5  2019-09-17 08:43:07  207  210  4965 2019-09-17 09:27:14 2019-09-17 09:38:28
6  2019-09-17 08:43:08  234  250  5163 2019-09-17 09:38:03 2019-09-17 10:18:29
7  2019-09-17 08:43:08  252  222  4911 2019-09-17 08:43:06 2019-09-17 09:43:58
8  2019-09-17 08:43:08  206  210  4900 2019-09-17 08:43:06 2019-09-17 09:38:20
9  2019-09-17 08:43:09  252  222  4911 2019-09-17 08:43:06 2019-09-17 09:43:58
10 2019-09-17 08:43:09  206  210  4900 2019-09-17 08:43:06 2019-09-17 09:38:20
11 2019-09-17 08:43:09  223  247  4909 2019-09-17 08:43:06 2019-09-17 09:16:00
12 2019-09-17 08:43:10  206  210  4900 2019-09-17 08:43:06 2019-09-17 09:38:20
13 2019-09-17 08:43:10  229  237  4909 2019-09-17 08:43:06 2019-09-17 09:16:00
14 2019-09-17 08:43:10  252  222  4911 2019-09-17 08:43:06 2019-09-17 09:43:58
15 2019-09-17 08:43:12  226  241  4909 2019-09-17 08:43:06 2019-09-17 09:16:00
```

then let's work out the absolute sum of seconds between the date and the min value.
if you need the actual value, you can read in the values as is, but you'll need to add in more logical steps to handle negative values.

```
s = abs(df3['min'] - df3['date']) / np.timedelta64(1,'s') 
print(s)
0        0.0
1        0.0
2        0.0
3        1.0
4        1.0
5     2647.0
6     3295.0
7        2.0
8        2.0
9        3.0
10       3.0
11       3.0
12       4.0
13       4.0
14       4.0
15       6.0
dtype: float64
```

you can do this a number of ways, but i'll just use `.loc` to set your values in order.

```
df3.loc[s <= 3, 'GroupSize'] = 3
df3.loc[(s > 3) & (s <= 7), 'GroupSize'] = 2
df3.loc[s > 7, 'GroupSize'] = 1
```

---

```
print(df3[['id','date','x','y','min','GroupSize']])
          id                date    x    y                 min  GroupSize
0   4900 2019-09-17 08:43:06  206  210 2019-09-17 08:43:06        3.0
1   4909 2019-09-17 08:43:06  234  236 2019-09-17 08:43:06        3.0
2   4911 2019-09-17 08:43:06  251  222 2019-09-17 08:43:06        3.0
3   4909 2019-09-17 08:43:07  231  244 2019-09-17 08:43:06        3.0
4   4911 2019-09-17 08:43:07  252  222 2019-09-17 08:43:06        3.0
5   4965 2019-09-17 08:43:07  207  210 2019-09-17 09:27:14        1.0
6   5163 2019-09-17 08:43:08  234  250 2019-09-17 09:38:03        1.0
7   4911 2019-09-17 08:43:08  252  222 2019-09-17 08:43:06        3.0
8   4900 2019-09-17 08:43:08  206  210 2019-09-17 08:43:06        3.0
9   4911 2019-09-17 08:43:09  252  222 2019-09-17 08:43:06        3.0
10  4900 2019-09-17 08:43:09  206  210 2019-09-17 08:43:06        3.0
11  4909 2019-09-17 08:43:09  223  247 2019-09-17 08:43:06        3.0
12  4900 2019-09-17 08:43:10  206  210 2019-09-17 08:43:06        2.0
13  4909 2019-09-17 08:43:10  229  237 2019-09-17 08:43:06        2.0
14  4911 2019-09-17 08:43:10  252  222 2019-09-17 08:43:06        2.0
15  4909 2019-09-17 08:43:12  226  241 2019-09-17 08:43:06        2.0
```

Comment: If I could give a super like, I would. Thank you so much, I owe you!

Comment: Thanks! A small Question. If i now would like to adjust the search within a minute interval, would i simply adjust the 's' to 'm'?

Comment: @kkjjnn yep, or you could do > 60 seconds ;) more [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html)

Comment: one question. I think something doesnt work out. Index 12-14 has 3 IDs that start in the same second, while the groupsize says 2. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @kkjjnn well, it looks like that min starts in the past, what logic do you want for times where the exit time is before the date time?

Comment: Done. Happy Holidays!

Comment: Regardless of time, it should only consider distinct IDs within a time interval (here 's'). So in the subset above we actially only have groupsize of 3 except for the two at 9:27 and 8:38, they would become groupsize 1 since there are no other individual Ids in the time. Does this make sense?

Comment: @kkjjnn, it does so for `4900` it should be `3` but we've set it to two, when we make the logical operation to compare the datetimes, which datetime do you want to use, the first, 2nd last?

Comment: I have reposted it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59490590/groupby-time-interval-and-find-unique-ids-with-similar-min-values-entry-time-va

Comment: I made a mistake in this one, I am deeply sorry. The min value can of course not be after the datetime value.