# Groupby time interval and find unique IDs with similar min values (entry time values)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by

Datanovice helped me in this post [Determining group size based entry and exit times of IDs in my df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59465127/determining-group-size-based-entry-and-exit-times-of-ids-in-my-df), so I got further with my problem. But, how can I now group the dataset (see subset below) into datetime seconds and look at the 'min' values of the IDs and count the unique IDs in the grouped 'date' second that have common 'min' values with a flexibility of a minute, for example. Is there any smart way to do this?

```
t_code  date                x   y   id      min                 max
4632    2019-09-17 10:17:10 209 201 5170    2019-09-17 09:38:19 2019-09-17 12:47:49
4632    2019-09-17 10:17:10 362 67  5163    2019-09-17 09:38:03 2019-09-17 10:18:29
4633    2019-09-17 10:17:11 209 200 5170    2019-09-17 09:38:19 2019-09-17 12:47:49
4633    2019-09-17 10:17:11 247 232 5177    2019-09-17 09:38:27 2019-09-17 11:14:21
4633    2019-09-17 10:17:11 337 157 5141    2019-09-17 09:37:22 2019-09-17 12:06:30
4633    2019-09-17 10:17:11 391 77  5284    2019-09-17 10:15:59 2019-09-17 10:18:30
4633    2019-09-17 10:17:11 363 69  5163    2019-09-17 09:38:03 2019-09-17 10:18:29
4633    2019-09-17 10:17:11 336 227 5282    2019-09-17 10:08:50 2019-09-17 13:13:44
4634    2019-09-17 10:17:12 247 232 5177    2019-09-17 09:38:27 2019-09-17 11:14:21
4634    2019-09-17 10:17:12 337 157 5141    2019-09-17 09:37:22 2019-09-17 12:06:30
4634    2019-09-17 10:17:12 391 76  5284    2019-09-17 10:15:59 2019-09-17 10:18:30
4634    2019-09-17 10:17:12 363 70  5163    2019-09-17 09:38:03 2019-09-17 10:18:29
4634    2019-09-17 10:17:12 335 227 5282    2019-09-17 10:08:50 2019-09-17 13:13:44
4634    2019-09-17 10:17:12 209 201 5170    2019-09-17 09:38:19 2019-09-17 12:47:49
4635    2019-09-17 10:17:13 391 77  5284    2019-09-17 10:15:59 2019-09-17 10:18:30
4635    2019-09-17 10:17:13 247 232 5177    2019-09-17 09:38:27 2019-09-17 11:14:21
4635    2019-09-17 10:17:13 209 201 5170    2019-09-17 09:38:19 2019-09-17 12:47:49
4635    2019-09-17 10:17:13 335 227 5282    2019-09-17 10:08:50 2019-09-17 13:13:44
4635    2019-09-17 10:17:13 363 69  5163    2019-09-17 09:38:03 2019-09-17 10:18:29
4635    2019-09-17 10:17:13 337 158 5141    2019-09-17 09:37:22 2019-09-17 12:06:30
4636    2019-09-17 10:17:14 337 158 5141    2019-09-17 09:37:22 2019-09-17 12:06:30   
4636    2019-09-17 10:17:14 392 76  5284    2019-09-17 10:15:59 2019-09-17 10:18:30
4636    2019-09-17 10:17:14 247 232 5177    2019-09-17 09:38:27 2019-09-17 11:14:21
4636    2019-09-17 10:17:14 209 201 5170    2019-09-17 09:38:19 2019-09-17 12:47:49
4636    2019-09-17 10:17:14 335 227 5282    2019-09-17 10:08:50 2019-09-17 13:13:44
4637    2019-09-17 10:17:15 209 200 5170    2019-09-17 09:38:19 2019-09-17 12:47:49
4637    2019-09-17 10:17:15 247 233 5177    2019-09-17 09:38:27 2019-09-17 11:14:21
4637    2019-09-17 10:17:15 357 69  5163    2019-09-17 09:38:03 2019-09-17 10:18:29
4637    2019-09-17 10:17:15 335 227 5282    2019-09-17 10:08:50 2019-09-17 13:13:44
4637    2019-09-17 10:17:15 390 74  5284    2019-09-17 10:15:59 2019-09-17 10:18:30
4637    2019-09-17 10:17:15 337 157 5141    2019-09-17 09:37:22 2019-09-17 12:06:30
4638    2019-09-17 10:17:16 335 227 5282    2019-09-17 10:08:50 2019-09-17 13:13:44
4638    2019-09-17 10:17:16 337 154 5141    2019-09-17 09:37:22 2019-09-17 12:06:30
4638    2019-09-17 10:17:16 209 201 5170    2019-09-17 09:38:19 2019-09-17 12:47:49
4638    2019-09-17 10:17:16 247 232 5177    2019-09-17 09:38:27 2019-09-17 11:14:21
4638    2019-09-17 10:17:16 356 69  5163    2019-09-17 09:38:03 2019-09-17 10:18:29
4639    2019-09-17 10:17:17 247 232 5177    2019-09-17 09:38:27 2019-09-17 11:14:21
4639    2019-09-17 10:17:17 335 152 5141    2019-09-17 09:37:22 2019-09-17 12:06:30
4639    2019-09-17 10:17:17 355 71  5163    2019-09-17 09:38:03 2019-09-17 10:18:29
4639    2019-09-17 10:17:17 392 74  5284    2019-09-17 10:15:59 2019-09-17 10:18:30
4639    2019-09-17 10:17:17 335 227 5282    2019-09-17 10:08:50 2019-09-17 13:13:44
```

I have a very long data set and a sample of the expected outcome is something like this:

```
t_code  date                x   y   id      min                 max                     GroupSize
4632    2019-09-17 10:17:10 209 201 5170    2019-09-17 09:38:19 2019-09-17 12:47:49     2
4632    2019-09-17 10:17:10 362 67  5163    2019-09-17 09:38:03 2019-09-17 10:18:29     2
4633    2019-09-17 10:17:11 209 200 5170    2019-09-17 09:38:19 2019-09-17 12:47:49     3
4633    2019-09-17 10:17:11 247 232 5177    2019-09-17 09:38:27 2019-09-17 11:14:21     3
4633    2019-09-17 10:17:11 337 157 5141    2019-09-17 09:37:22 2019-09-17 12:06:30     1
4633    2019-09-17 10:17:11 391 77  5284    2019-09-17 10:15:59 2019-09-17 10:18:30     1
4633    2019-09-17 10:17:11 363 69  5163    2019-09-17 09:38:03 2019-09-17 10:18:29     3
4633    2019-09-17 10:17:11 336 227 5282    2019-09-17 10:08:50 2019-09-17 13:13:44     1
4634    2019-09-17 10:17:12 247 232 5177    2019-09-17 09:38:27 2019-09-17 11:14:21     3
4634    2019-09-17 10:17:12 337 157 5141    2019-09-17 09:37:22 2019-09-17 12:06:30     1
4634    2019-09-17 10:17:12 391 76  5284    2019-09-17 10:15:59 2019-09-17 10:18:30     2
4634    2019-09-17 10:17:12 391 76  9000    2019-09-17 10:15:39 2019-09-17 10:18:30     2
4634    2019-09-17 10:17:12 363 70  5163    2019-09-17 09:38:03 2019-09-17 10:18:29     3
4634    2019-09-17 10:17:12 335 227 5282    2019-09-17 10:08:50 2019-09-17 13:13:44     1
4634    2019-09-17 10:17:12 209 201 5170    2019-09-17 09:38:19 2019-09-17 12:47:49     3
4635    2019-09-17 10:17:13 391 77  5284    2019-09-17 10:15:59 2019-09-17 10:18:30     1  
4635    2019-09-17 10:17:13 247 232 5177    2019-09-17 09:38:27 2019-09-17 11:14:21     3  
4635    2019-09-17 10:17:13 209 201 5170    2019-09-17 09:38:19 2019-09-17 12:47:49     3 
4635    2019-09-17 10:17:13 335 227 5282    2019-09-17 10:08:50 2019-09-17 13:13:44     1
4635    2019-09-17 10:17:13 363 69  5163    2019-09-17 09:38:03 2019-09-17 10:18:29     3
```

Help is much appreciated!!

Comment: I'm confused by what you're asking for. I must be misunderstanding. Normally, if you `groupby` a datetime down to the second, your result will have one row with that datetime down-to-the-second. I thought from your request you want to groupby datetime down to the second, but your 'sample of expected outcome' has multiple rows with the same datetime down to the second. Can you elaborate or clarify a bit what you're looking for in your expected output?

Comment: Maybe I use the wrong term with groupby. What i actually want is, in each 'date' column second, how many individual ID's have the same 'min' column value (this represents the entry time of people), or a value that ranges within the 'min' column .minute value. Does this make sense?

Comment: why is your `groupsize`=2 in the first row of your expected output? I only see one row in the top data table with both `date`=`2019-09-17 10:17:10` and `id`=`5170`?

Comment: Because in time 10:17:10 you have two individual IDs that have a min value in the same minute. I also indicated the time with a time_code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df['Groupsize']=( df.groupby(['date',pd.Grouper(key = 'min',freq = 'T')])
                    .id
                    .transform('size') )
print(df)

#or this
#df['Groupsize']=( df.groupby([df['date'].dt.second,pd.Grouper(key = 'min',freq = 'T')])
#                    .id
#                    .transform('size') )


    t_code                date    x    y    id                 min  \
0     4632 2019-09-17 10:17:10  209  201  5170 2019-09-17 09:38:19   
1     4632 2019-09-17 10:17:10  362   67  5163 2019-09-17 09:38:03   
2     4633 2019-09-17 10:17:11  209  200  5170 2019-09-17 09:38:19   
3     4633 2019-09-17 10:17:11  247  232  5177 2019-09-17 09:38:27   
4     4633 2019-09-17 10:17:11  337  157  5141 2019-09-17 09:37:22   
5     4633 2019-09-17 10:17:11  391   77  5284 2019-09-17 10:15:59   
6     4633 2019-09-17 10:17:11  363   69  5163 2019-09-17 09:38:03   
7     4633 2019-09-17 10:17:11  336  227  5282 2019-09-17 10:08:50   
8     4634 2019-09-17 10:17:12  247  232  5177 2019-09-17 09:38:27   
9     4634 2019-09-17 10:17:12  337  157  5141 2019-09-17 09:37:22   
10    4634 2019-09-17 10:17:12  391   76  5284 2019-09-17 10:15:59   
11    4634 2019-09-17 10:17:12  363   70  5163 2019-09-17 09:38:03   
12    4634 2019-09-17 10:17:12  335  227  5282 2019-09-17 10:08:50   
13    4634 2019-09-17 10:17:12  209  201  5170 2019-09-17 09:38:19   
14    4635 2019-09-17 10:17:13  391   77  5284 2019-09-17 10:15:59   
15    4635 2019-09-17 10:17:13  247  232  5177 2019-09-17 09:38:27   
16    4635 2019-09-17 10:17:13  209  201  5170 2019-09-17 09:38:19   
17    4635 2019-09-17 10:17:13  335  227  5282 2019-09-17 10:08:50   
18    4635 2019-09-17 10:17:13  363   69  5163 2019-09-17 09:38:03   
19    4635 2019-09-17 10:17:13  337  158  5141 2019-09-17 09:37:22   
20    4636 2019-09-17 10:17:14  337  158  5141 2019-09-17 09:37:22   
21    4636 2019-09-17 10:17:14  392   76  5284 2019-09-17 10:15:59   
22    4636 2019-09-17 10:17:14  247  232  5177 2019-09-17 09:38:27   
23    4636 2019-09-17 10:17:14  209  201  5170 2019-09-17 09:38:19   
24    4636 2019-09-17 10:17:14  335  227  5282 2019-09-17 10:08:50   
25    4637 2019-09-17 10:17:15  209  200  5170 2019-09-17 09:38:19   
26    4637 2019-09-17 10:17:15  247  233  5177 2019-09-17 09:38:27   
27    4637 2019-09-17 10:17:15  357   69  5163 2019-09-17 09:38:03   
28    4637 2019-09-17 10:17:15  335  227  5282 2019-09-17 10:08:50   
29    4637 2019-09-17 10:17:15  390   74  5284 2019-09-17 10:15:59   
30    4637 2019-09-17 10:17:15  337  157  5141 2019-09-17 09:37:22   
31    4638 2019-09-17 10:17:16  335  227  5282 2019-09-17 10:08:50   
32    4638 2019-09-17 10:17:16  337  154  5141 2019-09-17 09:37:22   
33    4638 2019-09-17 10:17:16  209  201  5170 2019-09-17 09:38:19   
34    4638 2019-09-17 10:17:16  247  232  5177 2019-09-17 09:38:27   
35    4638 2019-09-17 10:17:16  356   69  5163 2019-09-17 09:38:03   
36    4639 2019-09-17 10:17:17  247  232  5177 2019-09-17 09:38:27   
37    4639 2019-09-17 10:17:17  335  152  5141 2019-09-17 09:37:22   
38    4639 2019-09-17 10:17:17  355   71  5163 2019-09-17 09:38:03   
39    4639 2019-09-17 10:17:17  392   74  5284 2019-09-17 10:15:59   
40    4639 2019-09-17 10:17:17  335  227  5282 2019-09-17 10:08:50   

                   max  Groupsize  
0  2019-09-17 12:47:49          2  
1  2019-09-17 10:18:29          2  
2  2019-09-17 12:47:49          3  
3  2019-09-17 11:14:21          3  
4  2019-09-17 12:06:30          1  
5  2019-09-17 10:18:30          1  
6  2019-09-17 10:18:29          3  
7  2019-09-17 13:13:44          1  
8  2019-09-17 11:14:21          3  
9  2019-09-17 12:06:30          1  
10 2019-09-17 10:18:30          1  
11 2019-09-17 10:18:29          3  
12 2019-09-17 13:13:44          1  
13 2019-09-17 12:47:49          3  
14 2019-09-17 10:18:30          1  
15 2019-09-17 11:14:21          3  
16 2019-09-17 12:47:49          3  
17 2019-09-17 13:13:44          1  
18 2019-09-17 10:18:29          3  
19 2019-09-17 12:06:30          1  
20 2019-09-17 12:06:30          1  
21 2019-09-17 10:18:30          1  
22 2019-09-17 11:14:21          2  
23 2019-09-17 12:47:49          2  
24 2019-09-17 13:13:44          1  
25 2019-09-17 12:47:49          3  
26 2019-09-17 11:14:21          3  
27 2019-09-17 10:18:29          3  
28 2019-09-17 13:13:44          1  
29 2019-09-17 10:18:30          1  
30 2019-09-17 12:06:30          1  
31 2019-09-17 13:13:44          1  
32 2019-09-17 12:06:30          1  
33 2019-09-17 12:47:49          3  
34 2019-09-17 11:14:21          3  
35 2019-09-17 10:18:29          3  
36 2019-09-17 11:14:21          2  
37 2019-09-17 12:06:30          1  
38 2019-09-17 10:18:29          2  
39 2019-09-17 10:18:30          1  
40 2019-09-17 13:13:44          1
```

Comment: ansev!! Thanks a lot, that is exactly what i was looking for. Happy holidays!